# Getting a Callback after visjs finishes loading chart

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I'd like to get a callback from [visjs](http://visjs.org/) after it finishes loading a chart so I can then unhide the chart and stop a loading animation.  However, i don't see anyway to registrar a callback in the docs.

Now, I'm new to javascript so perhaps i'm not thinking about this correctly?  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you loading the data asynchronously?

Comment: The data is loaded asynchronously, and i get a callback when the load is completed.  Then, i process the data and call visjs.  I assume the visjs process is running asynchronously because my code continues to execute and returns control the to browser...but then i have to wait for the graphic to show up.  I want to instead display a loading graphic and then get a signal when the visjs graphic is finished 'rendering'.

Comment: I looked at the visjs documentation and, like you, didn't find a way to do it.  Yet, there are alternative graph libraries if that's an option for your project.  The one I like is [webix](http://webix.com/) which is well designed and very easy to use.  For comparison, here is a list of their [graph events](http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.chart.html) and some [sample graphs](http://docs.webix.com/samples/08_chart/index.html)

Comment: @Roberto see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of the creators of vis.js.

The visualizations of vis.js *should* load synchronously so there is no need for a callback. After checking though for the Timeline and Graph2d I saw this is not the case anymore, this is no intentional behavior. I've opened an issue for this here: https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1541

I don't know which visualization you're using, but a workaround for the Timeline and Graph2d is: the visualization is loaded synchronously, and the items are loaded on the next tick. So you can set a callback on a timeout after 0 ms:

```
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(...);

alert('The Timeline is visible but the items not yet (this is a bug)')

setTimeout(function () {
  alert('Now everything is loaded!');
}, 0);
```

Comment: agree that a callback does not seem to be needed. Nice work on the graph libray.

Comment: This is helpful for understanding the issue, but I don't think the workaround fully works. For large complicated timelines, there seems to be multiple loading stages.

Answer (score 3):

i solved the trouble with change event on first show.

```
 var firstshow=true;
 $scope.timeline.on("changed", function (properties) {
                if(firstshow)
                {
                    $scope.timeline.focus($scope.timeline.getVisibleItems());
                    firstshow=false;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was this:

```
timeline.on('finishedRedraw', function() {

    console.log('do something');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems this still hasn't been fixed. You can also hook into the **currentTimeTick** Timeline event. Note this events keep triggering so you can unsubscribe after the first time it triggers.

```
this.timeline.on("currentTimeTick", (prop) => {
        // Do something here
        // After fired the first time we un-subscribed
        this.timeline.off("currentTimeTick")
    })
```

Comment: This is a nice one, seems a bit better than `changed`.